# Ansible generating Haproxy config only for several servers from inventory

Tags: automation, haproxy, ansible-2.x

Is there a possibility to select a handfull of servers from the inventory for which would be generated the haproxy backend server configuration. The idea behind this is that we are running different  servers with different versions of the software and haproxy is routing the request to those servers depending on where the users want to go. 
I would like to be able to automatically generate haproxy configuration if somehow I could tag certain servers with V1.x or V2.x or so on.

This is what I could come up with as for a template. So far I only did the part which covers all the nodes, since I have no idea how to do the rest.

```
global
log /dev/log    local0
log /dev/log    local1 notice
chroot /var/lib/haproxy
user haproxy
group haproxy
daemon
maxconn     20000
tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048

defaults
    log global
    mode    http
    option forwardfor
    option http-server-close
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 300s
    timeout server 300s

    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend  http-in
    bind {{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}:80
    redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }

frontend  https-in
    bind {{  ansible_default_ipv4.address }}:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/redcap.pem
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https

    acl host_staging hdr(host) -i {{ website_hostname }}
    use_backend staging_v2 if host_staging


    default_backend             redcap_all

    acl IsV1   urlp(rc_vers) v1
    acl IsV2   urlp(rc_vers) v2
    use_backend redcap_v1 if IsV1
    use_backend redcap_v2 if IsV2

    acl IsV1H hdr(rc_vers) eq v1
    acl IsV2H hdr(rc_vers) eq v2
    use_backend redcap_v1 if IsV1H
    use_backend redcap_v2 if IsV2H

    acl IsV1P path_dir v1.9
    acl IsV2P path_dir v2
    use_backend redcap_v1 if IsV1P
    use_backend redcap_v2 if IsV2P

    acl IsV2S path_dir swagger-ui
    use_backend redcap_v2 if IsV2S

    acl IsV2SJ path_end swagger.json
    use_backend redcap_v2 if IsV2SJ


backend redcap_all
    mode        http
    balance     leastconn
    timeout     connect 1s
    timeout     server  300s
    timeout     queue   30s
    option redispatch
    retries 3
    cookie rc_cookie_vers insert indirect nocache secure
    {% for host in groups.nginx %}
        server {{ host }} {{ hostvars[host]ansible_default_ipv4.address }}:8080 cookie {{ my_tag }} check inter 1000 fastinter 500 rise 2 fall 1
    {% endfor %}

backend redcap_v1
    mode        http
    balance     leastconn
    timeout     connect 1s
    timeout     server  300s
    timeout     queue   30s
    option redispatch
    retries 3
    cookie rc_cookie_vers insert indirect nocache secure
    #    {% for host in groups.jetty %}
    #       {% if hostvars[host].my_tag == 'v1\.*' %}
    #        server {{ host }} {{ ip }}:8080 cookie {{ my_tag }} check inter 1000 fastinter 500 rise 2 fall 1
    #       {% endif %}
    #    {% endfor %}

backend redcap_v2
    mode        http
    balance     leastconn
    timeout     connect 1s
    timeout     server  300s
    timeout     queue   30s
    option redispatch
    retries 3
    cookie rc_cookie_vers insert indirect nocache secure
    #    {% for host in groups.jetty %}
    #       {% if hostvars[host].my_tag == '2\.*' %}
    #       server {{ host }} {{ ip }}:8080 cookie {{ my_tag }} check inter 1000 fastinter 500 rise 2 fall 1
    #       {% endif %}
    #    {% endfor %}


backend staging_v2
    mode        http
    balance     leastconn
    timeout     connect 1s
    timeout     server  600s
    timeout     queue   30s
    option redispatch
    retries 3
    cookie rc_cookie_vers insert indirect nocache secure
```

The hosts file looks like this:

```
[jetty]
test1 psql_host=test1 psql_db=testdb psql_user=testdb psql_pass=1vg324235dssdf871f2i1e2t14zx22yn14z51e2h1f1w1h8n1fg21f321imo1hhk1vgr psql_pass_plain='somepass' jasypt_pass=test jasypt_salt=my_test_salt psql_md_db=db_dictionary psql_md_user=db_dictionary psql_md_pass=15zm1l132432454twf1nlt1rag1t9g1tay1rbq1ni51tun1eau1n0o1w1y1kxy15yk my_tag='v1.2' ip=192.168.54.46
```

Comment: There are multiple ways to work with a part of servers from inventory (like using patterns, or loops). Please share a bit of your workflow (playbook code), so others could give advice.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a playbook code yet. I am just thinking on how can I make this work.

Comment: What's wrong with this template? I see you use `for host in groups.nginx` to iterate over different hosts

Comment: nginx groups covers all the app servers. I need to find a way to use 2 of those servers for the v1 backend and 1 for v2 in the same manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get you right, you may want to try this as one of possible solutions:

inventory:

```
[nginx]
host1 mytag=A
host2 mytag=A
host3 mytag=B
host4 mytag=C
```

template:

```
{% for host in groups.nginx %}
    {% if hostvars[host].mytag == 'A' %}
    server {{ host }} {{ hostvars[host].ansible_default_ipv4.address }}:8080 cookie v1.1 check inter 1000 fastinter 500 rise 2 fall 1
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I need. Let me impement it and test it.

Comment: Any idea if I have tags 2.1 and 2.2 but I want to have both 2.1 and 2.2 to be able to be added to the same backend is that possible?

Comment: @zozo6015 you can have complex if statement with OR, or several if statements.

Comment: I have implemented the solution above and I am getting the following: TASK [haproxy : Copy Haproxy template] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [vps141022.vps.ovh.ca]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'my_tag' is undefined"}

Comment: there was a typo in original answer. do you access my_tag via hostvars?

Comment: I have updated the question with hosts file entry for this also with the changes on the template. As it can be seen I have commented the loop and I am still getting the my_tag is undefined error message.

Comment: you refer `my_tag` inside `nginx` loop without `hostvars` prefix. also inside commented block you also refer `my_tag` without hostvars prefix.

Comment: I have fixed those and it's working fine now. I only need to figure out how to cover with  {% if hostvars[host].mytag == 'v1.*' %} all the v1.x possibilities.

Comment: also fixed the tag by using `{% if 'v1.' in hostvars[host].my_tag %}`